# Explicit wait not working NODEJS Selenium

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, webdriver, webdriverwait

THis is my code:

```
const { Builder, By, Key, until, WebDriver } = require("selenium-webdriver");
const firefox = require("selenium-webdriver/firefox");
const { app, BrowserWindow, Menu } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");
const electron = require("electron");


// function for implicit waits (sleep)
function sleep(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

function initSelenium() {
  async function startWebapp() {
    // build firefox webdriver and load web app
    let driver = new Builder()
      .forBrowser("firefox")
      .build();

    
    await driver.get("https://www.ea.com/en-en/fifa/ultimate-team/web-app/");

    
    // if login button appears press it - otherwise idle
    
    try {
      await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(By.xpath("/html/body/main/div/div/div/button[1]")), 30000);
      
      await sleep(10000);
      await driver
        .findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/main/section/nav/button[3]"))
        .click();
    } catch (err) {
      await sleep(10000);
    }
  }
  startWebapp();
}
```

I have tried mny varaíations of wait/until (elementIsVisable, and so on) but non is working.
When I remove my implicit waits (sleep) the button will never be pressed.

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2935

elementIsVisible expects a webelement not 'By' locator. So find the element first using

```
   element = driver.findElement(xpath)
   await driver.wait(until.elementIsVisible(element),5000)
```